# How to display live pipelines in Jenkins in a separate window?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I recently started learning Jenkins and had a question. The queue shows the history of running pipelines, the fact is that pipeline 1 can last 3 hours, and those launched after it for several minutes, and the still live pipeline is hidden at the bottom of the queue. Is there a plugin or other way to maintain non-closed pipelines at the top, or output them separately?

So far I have only been looking for answers on the Internet, and looking for plugins, as you can see, still without success. Since I don’t really know jenkins, I can’t try much on my own.